# ajax request and undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following js code:

```
var ret;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Pay/Build64/',
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(response) {
        ret = response.Message;            
    },
    async: false
});
alert(ret);
```

My action:

```
public JsonResult Build64()
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Message = "Test"
            });
        }
```

The Build64 is called. But `ret` is undefined. Where is a error?

Comment: check what response object returns console.log(response). whether it's   body or message

Comment: First, you can test with "console.debug(response)" in your "complete" callback.

Comment: If you want to access ret object outside store data into some dom or set x=$.Ajax (...) you got ajax object and then you can assigned

Comment: @user1260827 try using fiddler to see exactly what is being returned, it could be that the response is a text string and not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you return JsonResult you have to specify **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet** otherwise it will give error, for demo see [this](http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2011/03/understand-and-implement-jquery-getjson.html) blog link controller code.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of this. By default it will have an error, and since he doesn't have an error handler he is not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is related to your use of `complete` where you should be using `success`.

If you check [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the following surfaces:

- The `complete` callback is being passed `jqXHR` as the first argument
- While the `success`/`done` callback recieves `data` (the actual response data) as the first argument.

Since you're using `complete`, `response.Message` maps to a (undefined!) property of a `jqXHR` Object.

The solution to your problem is to use the `success` callback – or, even better, the `done` one, since `success` will be removed in jQuery 1.8.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Pay/Build64/',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
}).done(function(response) {
    alert('AJAX complete!');
    ret = response.Message;
});
```

Comment: @user1260827 Yap, I've been on the wrong track. See the updated answer.

Comment: I have found error. Need to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to `return Json...`.